# Vertically aligned middle an image in flexslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am using the flex slider jquery plug-in.
How i can vertically align middle an image in flex slider (images can be different sizes, large or small in the slides, because when i use small size image then it did not appear in middle, it appears at top which i don't want and get it in meddle) and it should also work for my responsive design.
check it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46eF6/) 
here is the flex slider code........

```
/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/  
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block; max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}
```

Comment: can you put it in jsfiddle. so that we can easily test this.

Comment: I put it on jsfiddle, you may check it.

Comment: There’s nothing to see in that fiddle, because jsfiddle does not provide the images for you. Use absolute links to actually existing images, instead of relative ones. (And you did not include the FlexSlider script as well.)